# Docker on EC2 - how to enable port to access oracle?

Tags: oracle, docker, centos, ports

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mysql:
    image: "mysql:latest"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
  backend:
    image: "backend:latest"
    ports:
      - 19001:19001
      - 80:80
      - "9001:9000"
    environment:
      DB_USERNAME: test
      DB_PASSWORD: test
      DB_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/test
      jdbc_url: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306
      JAVA_HOME: "/application/jdk8"
    # command: dockerize -wait tcp://wherehows-mysql:3306 -timeout 120s bin/playBinary
    links:
      - "mysql:mysql"
```

This works perfectly on my laptop.

When I move docker images to EC2 and start running it there (with same above docker-compose.yml file) - it gets stuck when backend tries to pull data from Oracle..

How exactly to set Docker so that it can access oracle (port 1521).

I have security group completely open (inbound/outbound) and can connect to oracle and pull data from bare EC2 but not from Docker running on EC2 (but it is ok on my Docker laptop).. 
It does not make sense to me..

Comment: why you not using ECS? go for manages solution instead of ec2

Comment: Because the end product (docker app) is not for me but for many different customers that might not use ECS. Any idea what might be a problem with EC2 and Docker?